Finding all $F$, $\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy) \subseteq F \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ such that $[F:\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy)]=2$
The answer to this question shows that for $n \geq 1$:
$[\mathbb{C}(x,y):\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy)]=[\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy,x):\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy)]=2n$.
For $n \geq 1$, denote $R_n=\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy)$.
Notice that $R_1=\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)=S_{\alpha}$, the field of symmetric polynomials w.r.t the exchange involution $\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$.
Of course, for every $m \geq 2$, we have $R_m \subsetneq R_1$.
Question: Can one find all $F$, $\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy) \subseteq F \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ such that $[F:\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy)]=2$?
For $n=1$ the answer is easy: $F=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
For $n=2$, what is a possible form of $F$ such that $[F:R_2]=
[F:\mathbb{C}(x^2+y^2,xy)]=2$?
$F=R_2(x^2)$ or $F=R_2(y^2)$, if I am not wrong.
Can one find all possible generators like $x^2$ or $y^2$?
What is the minimal polynomial of $x^2$ over $R_2=\mathbb{C}(x^2+y^2,xy)$?
(Notice that by the above mentioned answer, $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):R_2]=4$).
Thank you very much!

@DanielSchepler, thank you very much! Nice. What if $n$ is odd? You can write your comment as a partial answer, if you like.

@DanielSchepler, interesting, thank you for the elaboration. It is very close to an answer; I guess you can complete the missing details. (You can write an answer now or later, if you like).

Thank you. So the general case is quite similar to the special case $n=2$. Except $x^2$ or $y^2$ we can take $x^2-y^2$ ot any linear combination $ax^2+by^2$, with $a \neq b$.

Oh, by the way -- on the question of the minimal polynomial of $x^2$ over $\mathbb{C}(x^2+y^2, xy)$: that would be $t^2 - (x^2 + y^2) t + (xy)^2$.

Thank you, nice.

@DanielSchepler, please, could you take a look at the following 'similar' question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4939682/finding-mathbbcu-v-such-that-mathbbcu-v-xpyp-mathbbcx-y-f

First, let us set names for the fields, $K := \mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n, xy)$ and $L := \mathbb{C}(x, y)$.  Then we can exhibit a "rotation-like" automorphism $r \in \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i/n} x$, $y \mapsto e^{-2\pi i/n} y$, along with the "reflection-like" automorphism $s \in \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, $x \mapsto y$, $y \mapsto x$ that you outlined.  We can easily verify that $r$ has order $n$, $s$ has order 2, and $rs$ has order 2.  Therefore, $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $2n$.
According to this previous answer, if $n$ is odd then this group has exactly one subgroup $\langle r \rangle$ of index 2, whereas if $n$ is even it has exactly three subgroups $\langle r \rangle$, $\langle r^2, s \rangle$, and $\langle r^2, rs \rangle$ of index 2.  Let us examine these cases in more detail:

In all cases, we have $K(x^n - y^n) = \mathbb{C}(x^n, y^n, xy)$ is quadratic over $K$ since $(x^n - y^n)^2 = (x^n+y^n)^2 - 4(xy)^n \in K$.  This must be the intermediate field fixed by $\langle r \rangle$.
If $n$ is even, we have $K(x^{n/2} + y^{n/2}) = \mathbb{C}(x^{n/2} + y^{n/2}, xy)$ is quadratic over $K$ since $(x^{n/2} + y^{n/2})^2 = (x^n + y^n) + 2 (xy)^{n/2} \in K$.  This must be the intermediate field fixed by $\langle r^2, s \rangle$.
Similarly, if $n$ is even, we have $K(x^{n/2} - y^{n/2}) = \mathbb{C}(x^{n/2} - y^{n/2}, xy)$ is quadratic over $K$ since $(x^{n/2} - y^{n/2})^2 = (x^n + y^n) - 2 (xy)^{n/2} \in K$.  This must be the intermediate field fixed by $\langle r^2, rs \rangle$.


A great job :-)

Please, is it true that when $n$ is odd, there is a unique field extension of degree two over $\mathbb{C}(x^n+y^n,xy)$, which is $\mathbb{C}(x^n,y^n,xy)$? (this is the first option for odd $n$).

Yes, that's correct.

Thank you very much.
